# Why does Maven + Spring Boot create huge jar-files?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have the following Maven project structure:

```
parent_project
+--main_application
+--domain_models_and_repository
+--module_1
+--module_2
+--module_3
```

And the following simplified POMS:

**parent_project.pom**

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        [Spring Boot dependencies]
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>main_application</module>
        <module>domain_models_and_repository</module>
        <module>module_1</module>
        <module>module_2</module>
        <module>module_3</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**main_application**

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent_project</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>domain_models_and_repository</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>module_1</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>module_2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>module_3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**module_1**

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent_project</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>domain_models_and_repository</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**module_2**

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent_project</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>domain_models_and_repository</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**module_3**

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent_project</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>domain_models_and_repository</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>module_1</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>module_2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In reality I have more modules and more of them are dependencies of others. When I run `mvn install`
I get a 1.2GB file for the main application. I noticed that all dependencies of all modules are assembled
into the modules. Thus many jar-files are multiple times assembled into the file. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Every project is a boot project, which means that all your projects create runnable jars, which include the dependencies. So you basically get all dependencies 5 times in your jar, hence a large file. Why do all jars need to be spring boot apps/jars? Only the actual runnable application should be a spring boot application all the others can simply use the starters for dependency management and create plain jar files. Just remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from the parent and put it only in the project that should create an executable jar.

Comment: I don't know spring boot. But as no one else answered and I've much practice in using maven I will tell you about an idea. You added the spring boot dependencies to the parent pom. That means they are added to each POM that configures this parent. So these "jars" are added to each module. I don't know how the spring boot plugin works but it is possible, that ist includes each module !! and the dependencies f each module!! to the main jar. If i'm right adding the dependencies and the build configuration to the main pom and removing it from the parent pom would make your main jar smaller.

Comment: Why has my question been marked as a duplicate? The referenced thread is about another problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have declared the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in your parent pom. Due to this each created artifact will be an executable jar file and all these executable jar files contain the dependencies needed for the jar.

**domain_models_and_repository** contains all the dependencies declared in the parent and its own dependencies.

**module 1** and **module 2** contain all the parent dependencies, the locally declared dependencies and all dependencies expressed by the **domain_models_and_repository** project as well as the module itself.

**module 3** contains all the parent dependencies, its own locally declared dependencies and all other not yet available dependencies from **domain_models_and_repository**, **module 1** and **module 2** as well the those modules itself.

**main application** contains the parent dependencies its own locally declared dependencies and all other not yet available dependencies from **domain_models_and_repository**, **module 1** and **module 2** as well the those modules itself.

To fix remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from the parent and only add it to the pom of your main application. That way only your main application is an executable jar and all other modules are just plain jar files.

Comment: Reduced from 360 MB to 64 KB for me per service for 12 micro-services. Thanks a lot mate.